# Read text file in MATLAB for data analysis

Tags: matlab, import

I have uploaded the file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wY6lhme5pSK3XVlQmAUi1YdKQAic-GLo/view?usp=sharing). These are [some lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRdOE.png) from my txt file:

```
RSN1146_KOCAELI_AFY000 1.345178e-02
RSN1146_KOCAELI_AFY090 1.493577e-02
RSN1146_KOCAELI_AFYDWN 5.350641e-03
RSN4003_SANSIMEO_25862-UP 4.869095e-03
RSN4003_SANSIMEO_25862090 1.199087e-02
RSN4003_SANSIMEO_25862360 1.181286e-02
```

I would like to remove the data with `DWN` on 3rd line and `-UP` in 4th line. So the data will only have:

```
RSN1146_KOCAELI_AFY000 1.345178e-02
RSN1146_KOCAELI_AFY090 1.493577e-02
RSN4003_SANSIMEO_25862090 1.199087e-02
RSN4003_SANSIMEO_25862360 1.181286e-02
```

Then, I want to obtain the maximum value for `RSN1146` & `RSN4003`.

I tried to read the file with the code below:

```
Data=fopen('maxPGA.txt','r');
readfile=fscanf(Data,'%c %s')
```

It is weird as I cannot perform further analysis as the data is not imported as 2 column in MATLAB, any solution for this?

I tried:

```
Data= importdata('maxPGA.txt')
```

as well, but the data are grouped into 2 different table in this case.

Comment: 1) Can you embed a couple of the lines from your data file into the question so we don't need to open the file to see the format? and 2) Can you also provide an example of how you want the data to appear once it is in Matlab?  Your data file is a string for the first column and a float for the second so I'm not sure how you want it in two columns.

Comment: RSN1146_KOCAELI_AFY000 1.345178e-02
RSN1146_KOCAELI_AFY090 1.493577e-02
RSN1146_KOCAELI_AFYDWN 5.350641e-03
RSN4003_SANSIMEO_25862-UP 4.869095e-03
RSN4003_SANSIMEO_25862090 1.199087e-02
RSN4003_SANSIMEO_25862360 1.181286e-02
RSN4006_SANSIMEO_25130-UP 5.851637e-03


this is the example of my data, i want it to be appear in 2 columns so that  can remove the data with z direction and get the maximum of the file with similar names

Comment: Please update your question to add this information

Comment: I would use [textscan](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) for this.

Comment: Try [readtable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html).